# Swift 4 SDWEbImage Error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sdwebimage

i'm using SDWebImage in my application.While using getting the following error.I'm using Pod file as pod SDWebImage 4.3. [image]

Comment: try this : imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: yourplaceholderImage, completed: nil)

Comment: The error is shown at the line `let url = URL(string: "...")`. It has nothing to do with `SDWebImage`

Comment: Hi Akabari thanks for your reply...I have tried your solution but ts not working

Comment: @malik you are correct...Problem with string to url conversion...fixed it thank you.

Comment: @kavithaG can you try like this : URL.init(string: "yoururl")

Comment: @kavithaG can you share this link?

Comment: @Akabari ,its working,thanks for your effort.

Comment: @kavithaG You should use https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Answer (score 0):

pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'

create a swift file.

```
//  UIImageView+Extensions.swift
    import UIKit
    import SDWebImage

    extension UIImageView {

        func setImageUsingUrl(_ imageUrl: String?){
            self.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl!), placeholderImage:nil)
        }

    }
```